# Using a docker command in a Jenkinsfile gives me inconsistent result (works sometime, not found sometime)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('BuildImage') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'docker_pw', variable: 'DOCKER_PW')]){
                    sh '''
                        docker login -u ... -p ${DOCKER_PW} <dockerhub>
                        docker -v
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
...
```

I am building a Jenkins pipeline using `Jenkinsfile`. I am trying to build a docker image in the Jenkinsfile and push it to the dockerhub.

This works sometimes but sometimes I just fail with the message `line 2: docker: command not found`

This doesn't make sense to me because it works sometimes.

Do I have to use a different agent or something?

Comment: Does all jenkins slaves has docker installed?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to job trying to run on agents where docker is not installed.The best solution would be to use the labels. You can add labels on agents where docker is installed. That will help to identify what that agent can be used for. You can then specify in pileline with `agent { label 'docker' }`